# number of characters in a dynamic input box

Tags: html, css, pixel

I have a peculiar math problem. I am developing a hybrid mobile app using HTML/CSS/JS that will support multiple devices. for this reason I have not specified the input box width.

Now I need to truncate the text in the input box but since the width is not specified I cannot compare the length of the text field to a hardcoded value. I can however get the length of the  input box (in px) and the font size i use is fixed (10 px) 
Is there a way I can calculate how many 14px font size character can fit in a Xpx by Ypx input box?

Comment: You'll need to use a monospace font like courier for this to work. 20 `i`'s and 20 `W`'s will not be the same width otherwise.

Comment: If you force them to use monospace fonts you might be able to calculate this. Is there really no way you can just limit the amount of characters allowed on the inputbox?

Comment: You are doing a multi-device app but without flexible font sizing?

Comment: the css takes care of the width for the device. Its set to auto or 100%

Answer (score 0):

The way I've achieved this in the past may not be efficient but it does the trick (just about).

The key here is to clone your text and start making alterations to it. You can, with javascript do this cloning on the fly. Put it in an invisible div off the page, and then break the text in to single character chunks. Each of these characters can then be wrapped in a span.

The next step is then to ensure you know your input box's width, and start adding up the widths of your spans, starting from the front. This should just be a case of getting all of the span elements in your custom "off screen" div and iterating through them.

Once you hit the magic width number (or go over it) you know that the number of characters from your word that you can have in the box.

There is a slight quirk with what you're describing, of course, and that is that you may also need to work out how many "lines" of text you can fit in the box, and amend your "total width" accordingly (if you have 1 line that is 100px wide, your max width would be 100px, but if it's 3 lines deep, the max width would be 300px).

As I say though, this may not be efficient processor usage...but it is a solution, and it doesn't require your font to be a certain size or type.